# Send sales order confirmation only to shipping contact (not billing contact) in Odoo SA

Tags: odoo, saas, odoo-9

I'm using Odoo SA (SaaS version). Currently when a sales order is confirmed, it sends an email to the shipping contact as well as the billing contact. My billing contacts really only care about receiving the invoices. How can I stop the email from going to the billing contact, unless the billing and shipping happens to be the same.

Where would I start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello To solve this issue follow the following steps

### Step: 1 Active the developer mode

> TO active the developer mode in odoo v10 you go to the **setting ->
>   Active Developer mode** as shown in fig below.

### Step 2: Config setting

> TO stop the email notification go to the **Sale -> Sales -> Customer
>   -> Sales & invoice** as shown in below image.

[image: Email-Notification-stop]

Comment: Doesn't this stop all email notifications?

Comment: I have given the way which you asked the question. and describe more about the case where you failed. and share the screen shot if possible so I can help you more.